# jQuery Waypoints and translate3d

Tags: scroll, parallax, jquery-waypoints, translate3d

I'm trying to link two scripts: [Onepage scroll](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html)
 and [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/). The problem is that Onepage scroll uses translate3d to scroll the page, and because of this jQuery Waypoints fail. How do get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) and the event [`afterLoad`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterload-anchorlink-index) or even `onLeave`, which will do exactly the same as jQuery Waypoints.